# What does the (*) in (int (*)[30]) mean?

Tags: c

What does `(int (*)[30])` mean in C? For instance, in:

```
int (*b)[30] = (int (*) [30]) malloc(30 * sizeof(int [20]));
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm not asking what * means in C, I am referring specifically to the (\*), i.e. (int (*) [30]).

Comment: @Max: Ah, sorry.  I missed that you were asking about "`(*)`", not "`*`".

Comment: It means that you are casting to an array pointer so that it is casting to an pointer to an array of 30 integers

Comment: On a side note, never cast the result of `malloc` in C.  There is no need and you can run into problems if you forget to include `stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means, roughly, "is a pointer".

```
int (*b)[30]
```

This means "`b` is a pointer to an array of 30 integers".

```
(int (*) [30])
```

This means "cast to a pointer to an array of 30 integers".

Comment: And the other asterisk in the line means "multiply".

Comment: And a key point is that `int *[30]` would mean something quite different, namely an array of 30 pointers to `int`.

Answer (score 3):

```
int (*b)[30] = (int (*) [30]) malloc(30 * sizeof(int [20]));
```

Breaking it down:

```
      b        -- b
    (*b)       -- is a pointer
    (*b)[30]   -- to a 30-element array
int (*b)[30]   -- of int.
```

In both declarations and expressions, postfix operators like `[]` have higher precedence than unary operators like `*`, so `T *a[]` is interpreted as `T *(a[])`; IOW, `a` is an array of pointer to `T`.  To designate `a` as a *pointer to an array*, we have to force the grouping `T (*a)[]`.

Simlilarly, the cast expression `(int (*) [30])` means "treat the pointer value returned by `malloc` as a pointer to a 30-element array of `int`".  Note that, technically speaking, the cast expression is superfluous and should be removed.

The `malloc` call itself seems very wrong.  You're allocating 30 instances of a 20-element array of `int`, but assigning the result to a pointer to a 30-element array of `int`; that's going to cause problems.  Assuming you're trying to allocate a N x 30 matrix of `int`, the following would be safer:

```
int (*b)[30] = malloc(N * sizeof *b);
```

The type of the expression `*b` is `int [30]`, so `sizeof *b` is the same as `sizeof (int [30])`.

Answer (score 2):

How to parse C declarations and types: unwind them from outside in.

- `int (*b)[30]`.
- `(*b)[30]` is an `int`.
- `(*b)` is an `int` array of length `30`.
- `b` is a pointer to an `int` array of length `30`.

The nameless version `int (*) [30]` is entirely identical, just the name has been omitted.

If you have a copy of The C Programming Language, there's a program in there called `cdecl` that can transform such declarations into English.  There's been various modifications of it over time, for example [cutils](http://packages.debian.org/cutils) in Debian supports the nameless form, and [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) is online.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cdecl` to figure these kinds of things out:

```
cdecl> explain (int (*) [30]) 
cast unknown_name into pointer to array 30 of int
```

Answer (score 0):

(*) before a variable name means that is a POINTER.

We have just seen that a variable which stores a reference to another variable is called a pointer. Pointers are said to "point to" the variable whose reference they store.

Using a pointer we can directly access the value stored in the variable which it points to. To do this, we simply have to precede the pointer's identifier with an asterisk (*), which acts as dereference operator and that can be literally translated to "value pointed by".

Answer (score 0):

There's really nothing special about `(*)`. Since you're just referencing a type in your typecast (and not a variable, which has a name, of that type), you simply omit the name.  Here the parens are still needed to distinguish an array of pointers from a pointer to an array.